# Ajax returns response in error in Microsoft Lumia 950 mobile device

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, microsoft-edge

I wrote an ajax code,this works fine in all the devices but returns error in Microsoft mobile edge browser.

This is not returning timeout.
My ajax response always goes in error.
ready state : 0, status : 0, statusText: error, responseText:, textstatus:error,error:

My code is as below

Client.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script  src="/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script  src="/mobile/js/autocomplete.js"></script>
        <script  src="/mobile/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="col1">Let's start</div>
    <br />
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='savequote()'> Click here </a>

    <script>
    function savequote()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Server.php',
            timeout: 50000,
            async: false, 
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#col1').html('In process...'); 
            },
            success: function (data)
            {
                $('#col1').html('done');           
            },
            error: function (r, s, e) {
                var string = "readyState: "+r.readyState+", status: "+r.status+", statusText: "+r.statusText+", responseText: "+r.responseText+", textStatus: "+s+", error: "+e;
                $('#col1').html('Error : '+string);  
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server.php

```
<?php    
// current time
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
sleep(30);
// wake up !
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";    
?>
```

If I set sleep time to 10 second it works fine.

Comment: since both ajax timeout out and php time out is same so what happen is php still runs after 30 second and that's why ajax is returned with error. when php timeout is less then it successfully returns the response to ajax call without any error

Comment: removed timeout from ajax code, even I get the same error.

Comment: Issue i am facing only on micromax-edge browser.

Comment: Then it works fine. I added sleep time here because because my actual code (server.php api) takes more than one minute to respond.

Comment: I removed timeout from ajax code. as well i tried to set async:false then i am getting error:NertworkError.

Comment: go for the second solution then sleep time < ajax time out

Comment: updated code, still getting same error.

Comment: @ your url in ajax is `/view.php`. while your php code file name is `Server.php`. that cause the error

Comment: update code. this is test code.

Comment: have you checked set_time_limit ( int $seconds );
add this line in your php script at beginning of the file

Comment: `server.php` !== `Server.php`

Comment: changed file name. File name is not an issue. I observed a new thing. when I hit /Server.php on url , it says unable to reach to server in microsoft edge. if i change sleep time to 10s, it works.

Comment: @Greatym.com  i test your current code (timout= 50000 and sleep =30 ) . it works fine at my end

Comment: Issue is only on Micromax Lumia edge